# Add a column to a dataframe after calculating values based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the two following dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [[1, 'NEW'], [2, 'OLD'], [3, 'OLD'],[4, 'OLD']] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Age']) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [[1,2,3], [2,3],[1,3,4], [2,3]]})
print(df1)
print(df2)

    ID  Age
0   1  NEW
1   2  OLD
2   3  OLD
3   4  OLD

   ID
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [2, 3]
2  [1, 3, 4]
3  [2, 3]
```

I am trying to get the percentage of "NEW" IDs and add it as a new column to df2. I am doing it using the following function and it works fine. However, this seems to be not efficient for a large size dataframe. I was wondering if there is a more efficient/pythonic way to do this?

```
def id_list(x):
    ttl=0
    for i in x:
        if df1.loc[df1.ID == int(i), 'Age'].iloc[0] == 'NEW':
            ttl = ttl+1
    return ttl/len(x)

df2['percentage']=df2.ID.apply(id_list)
df2

    ID          percentage
0   [1, 2, 3]   0.333333
1   [2, 3]      0.000000
2   [1, 3, 4]   0.333333
3   [2, 3]      0.000000
```

Comment: Can `ID` column have single number repeated multiple times e.g. `[1,1,2,3]` or is it always unique set of numbers?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski. No it is always unique set of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `explode` and `groupby`:

```
df2['percentage'] = (df2.ID.explode()                   # flatten `ID` column
                        .map(df1.set_index('ID').Age)   # map ID to `Age` label
                        .eq('NEW')                      # compare with the label of interest 
                        .groupby(level=0).mean()
                    )
```

Output:

```
          ID  percentage
0  [1, 2, 3]    0.333333
1     [2, 3]    0.000000
2  [1, 3, 4]    0.333333
3     [2, 3]    0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

It is almost same idea with Quang ,`explode` first , then do `mean` with `level`

```
df2.ID.explode().map(df1.set_index('ID').Age).eq('NEW').astype(int).mean(level=0)
0    0.333333
1    0.000000
2    0.333333
3    0.000000
Name: ID, dtype: float64
df['New Ave']=df2.ID.explode().map(df1.set_index('ID').Age).eq('NEW').astype(int).mean(level=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

new_=set(df1.loc[df1['Age'].eq('NEW'), 'ID'].tolist())

df2['percentage']=df2['ID'].map(set).agg(lambda x: len(np.bitwise_and(x, new_))/len(x))
```

Outputs:

```py
          ID  percentage
0  [1, 2, 3]    0.333333
1     [2, 3]    0.000000
2  [1, 3, 4]    0.333333
3     [2, 3]    0.000000
```